# Can you recommend a java portlet software?

Tags: java, portlet

Currently I am developing java webapps using spring-mvc.
I would like to add a protlet feature to my webapps (something similar to Jira's homepage).

Can you recommend a software which will give me this feature?

Since I am already using  spring-mvc,I would rather use a third party instead of a new framework.

Answer (score 3):

Spring has [portlet support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/portlet.html), so you can continue using it as the framework. As for a portlet container - I'd recommend [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/).

Comment: you link to spring docs v2.0 you should at least link to 2.5.x

Comment: Thanks - updated to point to the 2.5.x docs

Answer (score 2):

You should use spring portlets. It's very similar to spring mvc.

But make sure that you use Spring framework V3+ to have portlet 2.0 support. Otherwise you don't have events etc.

As Portlet container/portal you might want to have a look at liferay which is pretty good looking or software like jboss portal server which needs a nicer theme but is (IMHO) better structured in the inside. (Might end up in less pain) ;-)